# Abstract servlet - how to prevent instantiation

Tags: java, servlets

I want two Java servlets share common `init()` and `destroy()` methods as well as initialization parameters. So naturally I delcared abstract servlet `public abstract class CommonConnectionServlet extends HttpServlet`, implementing mentioned methods. I also added to it a few initialization parameters in `web.xml` file. The I delcared two servlets extending my abstract servlet. However it doesn't work - glassfish server tries to create `CommonConnectionServlet` instance what raises an exception and servlets aren't starting.

Can I somehow prevent instantiation of an abstract servlet? Or, is it a bad idea to declare abstract servlet in general?

Comment: what is the exception?

Comment: maybe you spcified the abstract class in the web.xml?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Abstract servlets are fine, you can do that if you like. The problem seems to be that you declared it in the *web.xml*. Everything declared there (or annotated) as 'servlet' will be instantiated.

First, remove it from the web.xml. Then, if I understand correctly, you want to share some parameters through web.xml. The easiest way would be to create "context parameters" instead of "init-parameters", like this:

```
<web-app>
    <context-param>
        <param-name>name</param-name>
        <param-value>value</param-value>
    </context-param>
    ...
</web-app>
```

Then, you'll have to rewrite your abstract servlet to first try GenericServlet.getInitParameter(), but if that returns nothing, then retry ServletContext.getInitParameter().

This way subclassed servlets may override parameters if they need it, but the common shared parameters are used if not.